# Set editbox position and writing position, navigation bar and images

Tags: html, css

I'm new to **HTML** and **CSS**, and my first website is about Python programs, that the user can write into the editbox and then save it as Python file ( .py ). Right now I only created a navigation bar, editbox and also a Python icon.

I have some problems with my code, my Python icon is under the navigation bar and I can't see it, also, my navigation bar is not all over the screen, in the left side of the screen, I can see some space, and my last problem is with my editbox, I can only write from the middle and not from the beginning.

- How can I set my Icon to be on top of the navigation bar ?
- How can I modify the size of my navigation bar and set it all over the screen ?
- How can I write from the beginning and not from the center in my editbox ?

**HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content="This is an awesome website">
     <title>Make Python - Online Python Editor</title>
  <style>
      body {
          background-color: lightslategray
      }
      ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0px;
          width: 100%;
      }
      li {
          float: left;
      }
      .text {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 16px 18px;
          background-color: teal;
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      li a:hover {
          background-color: black;
      }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <a title="Main Page" href=""> <!-- Main Page Link -->
        <img style="border: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="python.png" alt="Python Image">
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="text" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="text" href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="text" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form>
        <input type="text" style="width: 1500px; height: 750px;">
    </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `z-index: 1;` to place the img tag on top of the ul tag.
- Right now your navbar is stretched to all of your page width. To use all of your
  page width. I guess you want your navbar links to spread within it.
  Use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between` for `ul` to
  achieve this.
- Use `text-align: left;` to write from the beginning.